# magento 2 collect totals for order like quote

Tags: magento2, orders

Is there any function to collect total like quote for orders ? or any way for this

```
$quote->collectTotals()
```

Comment: Can you write more? Why you need order collect total?

Comment: when one order created i remove all shipment and set new shipment with new amount .order item shipment and order shipment does not update after this then i want to collect totals and save the order

Answer (score 0):

You can set shipping in order and save:

```
$order->setShippingAddress($newShippingAddress)->setShippingAmount($newShippingAmount);
$order->save();
```